# How to represent the inside of a building for an app on android mobile?

Tags: java, android, cad

What software would i need to represent the inside of a building? I'm making an app which will locate the user and tell them where they are in the building and how to get to a certain room. How would i display this?

Comment: Are you asking us to write the app for you?

Answer (score 2):

Broad question is broad.

Take a look how Google I/O 2k11 [has mapped their floor plans](http://www.google.com/codesearch#qVeKhv9ZTQE/map/map.js&q=map.js%20package%3ahttp://iosched%5C.googlecode%5C.com). They have used `MapFragment` in `WebView`

Comment: My thoughts exactly when I saw this question. I'd try this, too!

Answer (score 0):

Thats a very challenging thing to do, because you need to get the schematics of the building where you are going to use this app, and I dont know if GPS is going to be of much use because of accuracy problems.

However, if you are making this app specifically for a particular building, like a mall or something, then you can use the wifi hotspots in the rooms to inform the device of the location and update on screen map using that information.

Developing an app that would help you navigate all buildings would, in my opinion, be impossible, unless there is a major cooperation.